# Google OAuth AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute 'docs'"

Tags: python, oauth

I'm trying to set up OAuth with Google services. Following the example [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html#UseAccessToken), I'm using:

```
try:
  from xml.etree import ElementTree
except ImportError:
  from elementtree import ElementTree
import gdata.calendar.data
import gdata.calendar.client
import gdata.acl.data
import gdata
import atom
import getopt
import sys
import string
import time

CONSUMER_KEY = "xxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxx"
TOKEN = "xxx"
TOKEN_SECRET = "xxx"

client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source='xxx')
```

And Python throws `AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute 'docs'"` when it tries to create the client.

Comment: What's the `import` statement you're using?

Comment: @icktoofay Added to original post, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've `import`ed `gdata` but not `gdata.docs.client`. Add this with the rest of your `import`s:

```
import gdata.docs.client
```